# Transposing (CaseToVars) in SPSS and renaming Variables with Existing Variables

Tags: spss

The dataset contains 6 variables such as:

```
StudentID  Sequence  Metric  Score  Interpretation  ScoreName
a123       8.00      13      540    12              P1_AIE
a123       9.00      14      550    19              P2_AIE
a123       9.00      15      500    13              P1_BP
a124       8.00      14      450    11              P2_AIE
```

I am ultimately trying to put all cases in one row such as:

```
StudentID P1_AIE_Seq  P1_AIE_Scr P1_AIE_Interp P2_AIE_Seq P2_AIE_Scr P2_AIE_Interp P1_BP_Seq etc.
a123       8.00       540        12            9.00       550        19            9.00      etc.
a124                                           8.00       450        11
```

These are students (StudentID) who repeatedly complete a battery of tests (Sequence); their results (Score) are tracked by a numeric value (Metric) and a string (ScoreName), and a numeric code is attached for the interpretation for each score (Interpretation).

Metric and ScoreName always correspond (i.e., 14 = P2_AIE in all cases). There are no duplicate records. Sequence isn't initially appropriate to use as an index because it repeats within the ID variable, but to get around that I use:

```
SORT CASES  BY StudentID Sequence.
compute dup = 0.
if $casenum>1 and lag(StudentID)= StudentID and lag(sequence) = Sequence dup=lag(dup)+1.
sort cases by StudentID dup Sequence.
CASESTOVARS    
/ID = StudentID dup
/Index = Sequence
/GROUPBY = Index/sep="_".
```

I am obviously constructing the syntax incorrectly---this doesn't put a single case on a row, it won't rename variables by the ScoreName---not even sure that SPSS can do this without python.

Any feedback or advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example of the desired output it looks like you are using `scorename` as the index, in which case there doesn't seem to be any need to fiddle with the `sequence` variable as you did.

This recreates your example data:

```
data list list /StudentID (a4) Sequence  Metric  Score  Interpretation  (4f3) ScoreName (a6).
begin data.
"a123"       8      13      540    12    "P1_AIE"
"a123"       9      14      550    19    "P2_AIE"
"a123"       9      15      500    13    "P1_BP"
"a124"       8      14      450    11    "P2_AIE"
end data.
```

Now if you run the following, you get all the data for each ID in one line:

```
sort cases by studentID ScoreName.
casestovars /id=studentID /index=ScoreName/sep="_"/groupby=index.
```

Comment: Eli, thank you for your help. When I run the syntax, I get a warning that each of the ScoreName variables has already been created, so SPSS creates a new variable (v1, v2, etc.). Going back to the data mock-up, I was hoping to get a single column for "P2_AIE" but for some reason I'm getting two columns ("P2_AIE" and "v1").

Comment: This is strange. when I just run the syntax in my post (the `data list`, the `sort` and the `casestovars`) I get the following variables with not problem: StudentID,   
Sequence_P1_AIE,  
Metric_P1_AIE,  
Score_P1_AIE,  
Interpretation_P1_AIE,  
Sequence_P1_BP,  
Metric_P1_BP,  
Score_P1_BP,  
Interpretation_P1_BP,  
Sequence_P2_AIE,  
Metric_P2_AIE,  
Score_P2_AIE,  
Interpretation_P2_AIE .

Comment: When I try it on subsets of data it works fine---so I'm assuming that the problem is with my data set. Thanks again for all the help

Comment: This is an interesting problem - if you manage to narrow this down to a reasonable size subset that creates these strange results please post it in a new question so we can try to figure it out.